# Hacer un Insert si no existe valor en una columna, sino hacer un update

Tags: php, mysql, condiciones

Hola les quería comentar que quiero hacer un Insert pero comprobar si existe un valor en una columna de la tabla antes de realizarlo, de ser asi que realice un update solo en el valor de la columna de la misma.

Les paso el codigo como lo tengo:

```
if(in_array($type, array('gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'php'))) {


if (!file_exists($carpeta)) {
mkdir($carpeta, 0777, true);

}


    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'])) {
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'], $url)) {

            // AHORA TENDRIA q verrificar si existe el nombre del archivo en 
 //la TABLA ARCHIVOS y hago un update a la fechamod del mismo/


$cnombre= "SELECT idarchivo,nombre FROM archivos WHERE nombre = '$nombre' 
AND idpersona = '$idpersona' AND idcategoria = '$idcategoria' AND idcarpeta 
= '$idcarpeta'";
if($conn->query($cnombre) === TRUE) {

$sql="UPDATE archivos set nombre='$nombre'


            where idarchivo='$row[idarchivo]'";}else{






// sino existe lo inserto 


            $sql = "INSERT INTO archivos 
(idpersona,idcategoria,idcarpeta,nombre,url,tipo,tama,fechamod,fecha,estado) 

                    VALUES 






    ('$idpersona','$idcategoria','$idcarpeta','$nombre',
    '$url','$type','$tama','$fechamod','$fecha','$estado')";


            if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                $valid['success'] = true;
                $valid['messages'] = "Successfully Uploaded";
            } 

            else  {

                $valid['success'] = false;
                $valid['messages'] = "Error while uploading";

                  }

            $conn->close();

        }
        else {
            $valid['success'] = false;
            $valid['messages'] = "Error while uploading";

        }
    }
}

echo json_encode($valid);

// upload the file 
}
```

Me sigue cargando otro registro... Bueno, si alguien me puede aportar una solución desde ya muy agradecido. Espero que se aya entendido la pregunta. 
Un saludo a toda la comunidad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias probar de esta forma, el codigo va comentado, me parece que es un error logico mas que todo.

```
   <?php
if(in_array($type, array('gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'php'))) {


    if (!file_exists($carpeta)) {
        mkdir($carpeta, 0777, true);

    }


    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'])) {
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'], $url)) {

            // AHORA TENDRIA q verrificar si existe el nombre del archivo en 
 //la TABLA ARCHIVOS y hago un update a la fechamod del mismo/

//declarar variable booleana
            $existe = false;

            $cnombre= "SELECT idarchivo,nombre FROM archivos WHERE nombre = '$nombre' 
            AND idpersona = '$idpersona' AND idcategoria = '$idcategoria' AND idcarpeta 
            = '$idcarpeta'";
//ejecutar query
            $result = $conn->query($cnombre);
//tienes que revisar estar parte porque no conozco la forma en que esta construido, lo que quiero validar es si la consulta tiene 1 es que ya existe, si tiene 0 no existe
            $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

            if($count > 0) {
                $existe = true;
            }

            if($existe == true){
                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                    $idArchivo = $row['idarchivo'];
                }

                $sql="UPDATE archivos set nombre='$nombre' where idarchivo='$idarchivo'";
            }

            if($existe == false){
               while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                $idArchivo = $row['idarchivo'];
                $nombre = $row['nombre'];

            }
            $sql = "INSERT INTO archivos 
            (idpersona,idcategoria,idcarpeta,nombre,url,tipo,tama,fechamod,fecha,estado) 

            VALUES 

            ('$idpersona','$idcategoria','$idcarpeta','$nombre',
            '$url','$type','$tama','$fechamod','$fecha','$estado')";
        }
// sino existe lo inserto 




        if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            $valid['success'] = true;
            $valid['messages'] = "Successfully Uploaded";
        } 

        else  {

            $valid['success'] = false;
            $valid['messages'] = "Error while uploading";

        }

        $conn->close();

    }
    else {
        $valid['success'] = false;
        $valid['messages'] = "Error while uploading";

    }
}
}

echo json_encode($valid);

// upload the file 
}
?>
```

Prueba y comenta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu colaboración amigo, de todas maneras me sigue tirando un error. Probé el código como me lo enviaste y me dice que no esta definido la variable $row[idarchivo]. Estos son los errores:  Notice: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int ------  Undefined variable: row in C:\wa...

Comment: Prueba a asignar lo que te devuelve la query a una variable "$row"

Comment: Asi como dice @JoseD.Jurado tienes que guardar el resultado de la query en una variable y recorrer ese resultado. Ya la edite, una pregunta:  pero a ti te insertaba?

Comment: Disculpen la demora, tuve un inconveniente personal. Probé el código y funcionó! Solo cambie el update, ya que quería que me modifique la fechamod (fecha de modificación) del archivo en el caso que se suba con el mismo nombre. Muchísimas gracias!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, no es necesaria la comprobación previa si tienes una clave primaria como idarchivo, puedes utilizar [REPLACE INTO](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html), en tu caso como utilizas solo una columna es más correcto hacer un insert con [insert .. on duplicate key](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Para tu ejemplo:

```
    INSERT INTO t1 (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```